# I am unable to sort data in ascending order using ORDER BY ASC

Tags: sql, database, sorting, sqldatatypes

The query I am running is

```
select accountid from general order by accountid ASC
```

The result I get is

```
accountid
------------
1 
1001 
1002
10021 
10026
1006 
1007
```

Why is it not ordering correctly?  It's a simple query and I am completely lost at how I can resolve this matter.

Comment: I am no SQL person, but if accountid was a string type, wouldn't that be the sorted ascending order?  could it be the type is not what you think it is?

Comment: In theory, you could use `CAST(accountid AS INTEGER)` in the select-list and order-by clause to get the numeric ordering you want.  But that will fail on account '1008A'.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The column type must be a numeric (`int`, `number`, `bigint`, etc) type..

Looks like right now it is a `VARCHAR` type column... which is sorted like a dictionary...

Comment: if you cannot change the column type, you can order by to_number(account_id) (which is maybe quite slow)

Comment: yes its varchar but why is it behaving like this can't we sort column with type varchar

Comment: @farkhunda. If you sort varchar, it sorts as strings (not numbers), and the output you show is the result

Comment: @farkhunda: when ordering character strings, the values are not treated as integers - they are treated as character strings and ordered as character strings (just as shown).  This was a reason why leading zeroes were popular in the dark ages of computing - alphabetic sorts sorted numbers with leading zeroes in the correct numeric order too.

Comment: @farkhunda: Strings sort character by character. The character `'2'` comes before `'6'`. So `'1002<whatever else the string contains, numbers letters what not'` is going to always come before `'1006'` If you want numeric sorting you will have to convert the strings to numbers before the sort. (Unless some of the strings aren't numbers, that would blow up then.)

Comment: Thanks everyone problem solved. I changed the query to

select accountid from general order by CONVERT(INT,accountid) ASC

Comment: If it is a new App or a new DB design, the best you can do is change the column type, CONVERT in a large amount of data could slowdown your query.

Answer (score 0):

If SolutionID is the VARCHAR Column and if it has some thing like Sol0, Sol1, Sol2, ....
then if you have to sort the column... use the below code

`cast (substring(SolutionID,4,10) as integer) desc`

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it works:

```
select accountid from general order by convert(int, accountid) ASC
```